# How to copy a file to network folder under OS X and Word 2004/2011

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, vba, microsoft-word-2011, word-2004

I am using Mac OS X. I have Word 2004 / Word 2011 on my Macs.

I need to know how to create a text file under Word 2004/2011 and copy that file to my network share folder. I have to write a macro preferably.

Comment: Do you need this to happen every time you save a file?

Answer (score 0):

> Do you need this to happen every time you save a file?

No. The user will be working on word document (doing some changes) prior to our step of copying the file to network folder. the user is required to store the documents to some network location once the user completed his work. So, I am hoping to create a menu/toolbar. clicking on that would copy the current (active) document along with some other files where the current document is stored to network location.

Comment: You should save this kind of conversation for the comments.